# Fetch request to backend within same domain fails net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, router, apache2

I have a react application *zz* that has a backend and frontend that are hosted separately. The front is hosted on https://toing.com/zz (on a stock hosting plan) that needs to connect to the backend at https://api.toing.com hosted on apache.

I use a valid SSL certificate and everything was working perfectly until this morning until around 9h (UK time), when suddenly we started getting

```
 net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

responses for our javascript fetch requests from the frontend only on our local network. It works fine outside the network.

To explain a bit more, we have a commercial fiber router and our SSL port is forwarded directly to the server running apache.

So if we try to make requests from https://toing.com/zz to the API connected to the local network of the router, we get the above error.
However everything works as expected from outside the host's router.

- I have double checked that the certificate hasn't expired
- I have also checked that the datetime is the same for the front and
  back.
- We did not mess with the router
- Checked all firewalls and routing (basically nothing was ever changed)
- No issues on apache logs

I do not understand why such an error would occur. Have you had similar experiences?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, but check that the site is properly setup for both IPv4 and IPv6 in case there are DNS entries for both IPv4 and IPv6. It is a common problem that a site is only properly setup for IPv4 and this seems to work from everywhere testet - but fails to work for networks which actually have IPv6 connectivity (i.e. local network, often mobile networks).

Additionally check that the results from a DNS lookup for both IPv4 and IPv6 are the same from all places and that there are no local hosts files which might have conflicting settings.

Comment: Thank you for your response, It seems to be an issue with the DNS cache of the livebox router, if I add a hosts route on my computer it works:
`192.162.1.88 api.toing.com`
I don't see anyway to clear the cache, so I guess i'm stuck?

Comment: @toing_toing: the routers DNS cache is likely clearly if you reboot the router. Other than that: DNS explicitly allows caching. The time caching is allowed is given in the DNS responses. Often this time is days.